# How to attribute video under CC BY licence 3.0

Tags: copyright, creative-commons, youtube

I want to use video from youtube, which is under CC BY licence 3.0 on another resources, where might be or might be not description section. I was thinking, that I can just add attribution "credits" screen for a few seconds at the end of the video, but Im not sure if there any specific rules for that. Like how long it should be or minimum font size (it might be a real problem if Im gonna use a lot of videos in one)...

By attribution "credits" screen I mean something like that on the white screen
"Creative Commons 10th Birthday Celebration San Francisco" by tvol is licensed under CC BY 2.0
available here: https://www.flickr.com/photos/sixteenmilesofstring/8256206923/in/set-72157632200936657

Thank you in advance!